# Stack Overflow now automatically shows pypi when searching for pypy

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, search

After the recent software update, pypi and pypy are the same thing. The problem is one is a python interpreter the other is a python package index. There is almost zero overlap. I used to look for pypy questions (sometimes buried inside some other questions) and answer them. Now it's no longer working, because the signal to noise ratio is very low. Can something be done?

Comment: What do you enter and what does your URL look like when you search?

Comment: This is the cost of stemming currently, so it's intentional.  We'll see what can be improved but since there is a way to search for literals (a few ways really), this isn't priority #1.  It is on my list though, don't think this is being ignored.

Comment: thanks a lot, I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping the term in quotes seems to enforce more literal results:

```
"pypi"
```

as far as I can tell, searching in the *tag* is literal as well:

```
[pypi]
```

Comment: Indeed. And [combining them will give the compulsive retaggers something to feed on](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22pypi%22+-[pypi])

Comment: ah cool, this solves the problem :)